# Drag functionality and Click-to-expand with D3 force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag, force-layout

simple question.

I implemented both drag functionality on my force-directed graph as below:

```
 var drag = force.drag()
                    .on("dragstart", dragstart);
```

As well as enable an "expand" functionality when you click on a node to see its childrens.

The problem that i encounter is that when i drag the node, once i leave the mouse button, the on-click event kicks in and expand (or collapse) the node.

How can i prevent that?

Comment: There's an example of how to deal with this issue on the [api reference page](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#wiki-on) of the `d3.behavior.drag` function.